# Error: [ng:areq] from angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller, mean-stack

This is a long shot, but has anyone seen this error before? I am trying to add 'Transporters' using express, angular and mongoDB. I get this error whenever I access a page ruled by the transporters controller:

```
Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.12/ng/areq?p0=TransportersController&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.min.js:6:450
    at tb (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.min.js:18:360)
    at Pa (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.min.js:18:447)
    at http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.min.js:62:17
    at http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.min.js:49:43
    at q (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.min.js:7:386)
    at H (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.min.js:48:406)
    at f (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.min.js:42:399)
    at http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.min.js:42:67
```

The transporters controller looks like this:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('mean.transporters').controller('TransportersController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$location', 'Global', 'Transporters', function ($scope, $routeParams, $location, Global, Transporters) {
    $scope.global = Global;

    $scope.create = function() {
        var transporter = new Transporters({
            name: this.name,
            natl_id: this.natl_id,
            phone: this.phone
        });
        transporter.$save(function(response) {
            $location.path('transporters/' + response._id);
        });

        this.title = '';
        this.content = '';
    };

    $scope.remove = function(transporter) {
        if (transporter) {
            transporter.$remove();

            for (var i in $scope.transporters) {
                if ($scope.transporters[i] === transporter) {
                    $scope.transporters.splice(i, 1);
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            $scope.transporter.$remove();
            $location.path('transporters');
        }
    };

    $scope.update = function() {
        var transporter = $scope.transporter;
        if (!transporter.updated) {
            transporter.updated = [];
        }
        transporter.updated.push(new Date().getTime());

        transporter.$update(function() {
            $location.path('transporters/' + transporter._id);
        });
    };

    $scope.find = function() {
        Transporters.query(function(transporters) {
            $scope.transporters = transporters;
        });
    };

    $scope.findOne = function() {
        Transporters.get({
            transporterId: $routeParams.transporterId
        }, function(transporter) {
            $scope.transporter = transporter;
        });
    };
}]);
```

In my views I call the list and create methods. They generate the above error

I got this from the angular docs for [ng:areq](http://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng%3aareq) though still can't figure what's going on

> AngularJS often asserts that certain values will be present and truthy
>   using a helper function. If the assertion fails, this error is thrown.
>   To fix this problem, make sure that the value the assertion expects is
>   defined and truthy.

Here's the view that calls the controller `public/views/transporters/list.html`:

```
<section data-ng-controller="TransportersController" data-ng-init="find()">
    <ul class="transporters unstyled">
        <li data-ng-repeat="transporter in transporters">
            <span>{{transporter.created | date:'medium'}}</span> /
            <h2><a data-ng-href="#!/transporters/{{transporter._id}}">{{transporter.name}}</a></h2>
            <div>{{transporter.natl_id}}</div>
            <div>{{transporter.phone}}</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <h1 data-ng-hide="!transporters || transporters.length">No transporters yet. <br> Why don't you <a href="/#!/transporters/create">Create One</a>?</h1>
</section>
```

Transporters service code:

```
angular.module('transporterService', [])
    .factory('Transporter', ['$http', function($http){
        // all return promise objects
        return {
            get: function(){
                return $http.get('/api/transporters');
            },
            create: function(transporterData){
                return $http.post('/api/transporters', transporterData);
            },
            delete: function(id){
                return $http.delete('/api/transporters/'+id);
            }
        };
    }]);
```

Comment: Could you provide the code snippet that assigns the controller to a view?

Comment: Could you please provide the Transporters service code as well?

Comment: got it, but I think I fixed this somehow

Comment: Make sure your controller is available or not. Possible solutions are controller name is misspelled or js file is not updated or saved

Comment: I got this error when I had an error in my controller js file. Put a line of code between an if block and an else block. I'm not usually a front-end developer, so I thought something would have stopped me from using bad javascript, but this was the first error that came up.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

I experienced this error once. The problem was I had defined angular.module() in two places with different arguments.

Eg:

```
var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);
```

in other place,

```
var MyApp2 = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngAnimate']);
```

Comment: dependency injection ftw

Comment: What is the solution for this?

Comment: the solution is to not give two separate modules the same name. in @Tharanga's sample code, both modules have the name 'MyApp'. This is a problem; you can't redefine a module. So a solution would be to change the second module's name to 'MyOtherApp' or 'MyApp2' or anything else that isn't 'MyApp'.

Comment: In whole project code base, there should be at most one place where we can initialize app module with given name that is `var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);`. and any put any injection in the [] bracket that may be required in whole code base. In rest of the files/place we should only be retrieving the app module i.e `var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp');` -- with no [] bracket.

Answer (score 33):

I've gotten that error twice:

1) When I wrote:

```
var app = module('flapperNews', []);
```

instead of:

```
var app = angular.module('flapperNews', []);
```

2) When I copy and pasted some html, and the controller name in the html did not exactly match the controller name in my app.js file, for instance:

index.html:

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
...
...
<body ng-app="flapperNews" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
```

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('flapperNews', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl', ....
```

In the html, the controller name is "MainCtrl", and in the js I used the name "MyCtrl".

There is actually an error message embedded in the error url:

> Error: [ng:areq]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.2/ng/areq?p0=**MainCtrl**&p1=**not**%20**a**%20**function**%2C%20**got**%20**undefined**

Here it is without the hieroglyphics:

> **MainCtrl not a function got undefined**

In other words, "There is no function named MainCtrl.  Check your spelling."

Answer (score 25):

I ran into this issue when I had defined the module in the Angular controller but neglected to set the app name in my HTML file. For example:

```
<html ng-app>
```

instead of the correct:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
```

when I had defined something like:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller(...
```

and referenced it in my HTML file.

Answer (score 15):

you forgot to include the controller in your index.html. The controller doesn't exist.

```
<script src="js/controllers/Controller.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 5):

I had same error and the issue was that I didn't inject the new module in the main application

```
var app = angular.module("geo", []);
...

angular
    .module('myApp', [
        'ui.router',
        'ngResource',
        'photos',
        'geo' //was missing
    ])
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, saved a lot of time.

Answer (score 4):

Check the name of your angular module...what is the name of your module in your app.js?

In your TransportersController, you have:

```
angular.module('mean.transporters')
```

and in your TransportersService you have:

```
angular.module('transporterService', [])
```

You probably want to reference the same module in each:

```
angular.module('myApp')
```

Answer (score 4):

I had this error too, I changed the code like this then it worked.

html

```
 <html ng-app="app">

   <div ng-controller="firstCtrl">
       ...
   </div>

 </html>
```

app.js

```
(function(){

    var app = angular.module('app',[]);

    app.controller('firstCtrl',function($scope){    
         ...
    })

})();
```

You have to make sure that the name in module is same as ng-app

then div will be in the scope of firstCtrl

Answer (score 4):

The same problem happened with me but my problem was that I wasn't adding the **FILE_NAME_WHERE_IS_MY_FUNCTION.js**

so my **file.html** never found where my function was

> Once I add the "file.js" I resolved the problem

```
<html ng-app='myApp'>
    <body ng-controller='TextController'>
    ....
    ....
    ....
    <script src="../file.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

:)

Comment: Yes, this was my problem.

Answer (score 3):

I've got that error when the controller name was not the same (case sensitivity!):

```
.controller('mainCOntroller', ...  // notice CO
```

and in view

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="mainController">  <!-- notice Co -->
```

Answer (score 3):

I got this same error when I included the entire controller file name in the Routes like this:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider 
    .when('/', { 
        templateUrl: 'home.html',
        controller: 'mainController.js'
    })

    .when('/portfolio', { 
        templateUrl: 'portfolio.html',
        controller: 'mainController.js'
    })
});
```

When it should be

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider 
    .when('/', { 
        templateUrl: 'home.html',
        controller: 'mainController'
    })

    .when('/portfolio', { 
        templateUrl: 'portfolio.html',
        controller: 'mainController'
    })
});
```

Angular takes certain things you name like the app and controller and expounds on them in directives and across your app, take care to name everything consistently and check for this when debugging

Answer (score 2):

I know this sounds stupid, but don't see it on here yet :). I had this error caused by forgetting the closing bracket on a function and its associated semi-colon since it was anonymous assigned to a var at the end of my controller.

It appears that many issues with the controller (whether caused by injection error, syntax, etc.) cause this error to appear.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me when I have multiple angular modules in the same page

I encountered this error when I used partial views

One partial view had

```
<script src="~/Scripts/Items.js"></script>
<div ng-app="SearchModule">
    <div ng-controller="SearchSomething" class="col-md-1">
        <input class="searchClass" type="text" placeholder="Search" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Other had

```
<div ng-app="FeaturedItems" ng-controller="featured">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in Items">{{item.Name}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I had them in same module with different controller and it started working

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error in a demo app that was concerned with security and login state.  None of the other solutions helped, but simply **opening a new anonymous browser window** did the trick.

Basically, there were cookies and tokens left from a previous version of the app which put AngularJS in a state that it was never supposed to reach.  Hence the `areq` assertions failed.

Answer (score 1):

There's also another way this could happen.

In my app I have a main module that takes care of the ui-router state management, config, and things like that. The actual functionality is all defined in other modules.

I had defined a module

```
angular.module('account', ['services']);
```

that had a controller 'DashboardController' in it, but had forgotten to inject it into the main module where I had a state that referenced the DashboardController.

Since the DashboardController wasn't available because of the missing injection, it threw this error.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I included `app.js` below the controller while `app.js` should include above any controller like

```
<script src="js/app.js"></script> 
<script src="js/controllers/mainCtrl.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had done everything right other than setting controller in $stateProvider. I used filename rather than variable name.

Following code is wrong:

```
formApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider

       .state('management', {
            url: '/management',
            templateUrl: 'Views/management.html',
            controller: 'Controllers/ManagementController.js'
        });
```

and this is the right approach;

```
formApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider

       .state('management', {
            url: '/management',
            templateUrl: 'Views/management.html',
            controller: 'ManagementController'
        });
```

Make sure you noticed;

> controller: 'ManagementController'

And for those who are curious about my controller file ManagementController.js, it looks like the this;

```
formApp.controller('ManagementController', ['$scope', '$http', '$filter', '$state',function(scope, http, filter, state) {
    scope.testFunc = function() {
        scope.managementMsg  = "Controller Works Fine.";
    };
}]);
```

For those who want a quick-start angular skeleton for above example check this link https://github.com/zaferfatih/angular_skeleton

Answer (score 1):

The error will be seen when your controller could not be found in the application.  You need to make sure that you are correct using values in `ng-app` and `ng-controller` directives

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me when using ng-include, and the included page had controllers defined.  Apparently that's not supported.

[Controller loaded by ng-include not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26777381/controller-loaded-by-ng-include-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

I have made a stupid mistake and wasted lot of time so adding this answer over here so that it helps someone

I was incorrectly adding the $scope variable(dependency)(was adding it without single quotes)

for example what i was doing was something like this

```
angular.module("myApp",[]).controller('akshay',[$scope,
```

where the desired syntax is like this

```
angular.module("myApp",[]).controller('akshay',['$scope',
```

Answer (score 1):

// include controller dependency in case of third type

```
 var app = angular.module('app', ['controller']);
```

// first type to declare controller 
// this doesn't work well

```
var FirstController = function($scope) {
    $scope.val = "First Value";
}
```

//Second type of declaration

```
app.controller('FirstController', function($scope) {
    $scope.val = "First Controller";
});
```

// Third and best type

```
angular.module('controller',[]).controller('FirstController', function($scope) {
    $scope.val = "Best Way of Controller";
});
```