# Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'DoughnutCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

when i use ng-controller='DoughnutCtrl' in dive it give the error

> Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'DoughnutCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

My chart.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('portfolioApp',['chart.js']).
controller('DoughnutCtrl', function ($scope) 
{
$scope.data = [[
    {
      value: 80,
      color: "#949FB1",
      highlight: "#A8B3C5",
      label: "80%"
    },
    {
      value: 20,
      color: "#4D5360",
      highlight: "#616774",
      label: ""
    }

  ],
  [
    {
      value: 70,
      color: "#000000",
      highlight: "#A8B3C5",
      label: "80%"
    },
    {
      value: 30,
      color: "#ffffff",
      highlight: "#167740",
      label: ""
    }
  ]];
 });
```

and my html code is

```
<div ng-app="portfolioApp">
<div ng-controller="DoughnutCtrl">

  <canvas tc-chartjs-doughnut chart-options="options" chart-data="data" auto-legend></canvas>

</div>
```

i'm new to angularjs can anyone explain why this is happening?.

Comment: where do you place javascript?

Comment: where did i need to put the javascript?.

Comment: either head or html, but not in something like $(document).ready

Comment: did you include controller js on page ?

Comment: you mean lode the controller javascript?.

Comment: yes you should include it on page after angular.js and app.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the issue is you are trying to use **directive** `tc-chartjs-doughnut` in canvas element

```
<canvas tc-chartjs-doughnut chart-options="options" chart-data="data" auto-legend></canvas>
```

which is [tc-angular-chartjs](https://github.com/carlcraig/tc-angular-chartjs) module.

In angular module as `angular.module('portfolioApp',['chart.js']).`, you are adding `chart.js` module which is other module of [angularj-chart.js](https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js)

So using different modules for HTML and JS will not work. You have to select one module and **add it's related dependancy** in project.

In HTML you have defined `chart-options="options"` which is not bind to `$scope` so you have to defined looked like below.

```
$scope.options = {}; // Add available options based on requirement
```

Check below working example:

```js
angular
  .module('myModule',['tc.chartjs'])
  .controller( 'DoughnutCtrl', function( $scope ) {

    // Chart.js Data
    $scope.data = [
      {
        value: 300,
        color:'#F7464A',
        highlight: '#FF5A5E',
        label: 'Red'
      },
      {
        value: 50,
        color: '#46BFBD',
        highlight: '#5AD3D1',
        label: 'Blue'
      },
      {
        value: 100,
        color: '#FDB45C',
        highlight: '#FFC870',
        label: 'Yellow'
      }
    ];

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://carlcraig.github.io/tc-angular-chartjs/js/vendor/tc-angular-chartjs.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myModule">
  <div ng-controller="DoughnutCtrl">

    <canvas tc-chartjs-doughnut chart-data="data" auto-legend></canvas>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I removed  "tc-chartjs-doughnut chart-options="options"" still get the same error.

Comment: Issue must be related to adding all required file which is highlighted in my answer...Make sure that all files are included in HTML...If issue occur create  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: what you mean?. can you explain?.

Comment: Check updated answer with working code and compare it with your code to understand and solve the issue which is explain in my answer... :)

Comment: ok will do man. thank you very much. can you tell me your skype or other social account name?. again thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you've defined the module `portfolioApp` twice.

```
// This creates the module and passes dependencies to it
angular.module('portfolioApp', ['chart.js']);
```

vs

```
// This only gets the module after it's been defined
angular.module('portfolioApp');
```

Try this question here, seems to be a similar error:
[Error: [ng:areq] from angular controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21673404/error-ngareq-from-angular-controller)

Comment: Do you have multiple places in your code that define the module? If so, they must all be getters, while the definition (passing ['charts.js'] to it) must happen only once.

Comment: You can only create a module once. Calling `angular.module('name', [])` creates the module. Calling `angular.module('name')` gets the instance of the module you created. Are you sure you are creating it only once?

Comment: i used as name my app name. is it ok?.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: what should be included as name?.

Comment: The name of your module

Answer (score 0):

You just use below codes

```
'use strict';

  var app =   angular.module('portfolioApp',['chart.js']);
    app.controller('DoughnutCtrl', function ($scope) 
    {
    $scope.data = [[
        {
          value: 80,
          color: "#949FB1",
          highlight: "#A8B3C5",
          label: "80%"
        },
        {
          value: 20,
          color: "#4D5360",
          highlight: "#616774",
          label: ""
        }

      ],
      [
        {
          value: 70,
          color: "#000000",
          highlight: "#A8B3C5",
          label: "80%"
        },
        {
          value: 30,
          color: "#ffffff",
          highlight: "#167740",
          label: ""
        }
      ]];
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are referring to the example from this link : http://carlcraig.github.io/tc-angular-chartjs/doughnut/

As you can see the module you need to inject is 'tc.chartjs' not 'chart.js'. So fix it to be :

```
var app =   angular.module('portfolioApp',['tc.chartjs']);
```

Next ensure your div with ng-app encloses the div with ng-controller

```
<div ng-app="portfolioApp">
  <div ng-controller="DoughnutCtrl">
     <canvas tc-chartjs-doughnut chart-options="options" chart-data="data" auto-legend>
      </canvas>
   </div>
</div>
```