# Reference Error: Angular not defined

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack

```
describe('Nav Bar', function() {
var injector;
var element;
var scope;
var compiler;
var httpBackend;

beforeEach(function() {
injector = angular.injector(['myApp', 'ngMockE2E']);
intercepts = {};

injector.invoke(function($rootScope, $compile, $httpBackend) {
  scope = $rootScope.$new();
  compiler = $compile;
  httpBackend = $httpBackend;
});
});
```

The below is the html file.

```
 <html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.js">
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/6-examples/app.js">
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <user-menu></user-menu>
  </body>
</html>
```

This code is written as a test to check if the user info is getting stored correctly.
How to resolve the error?

Comment: Typically, this happens when you don't include the angularjs script as part of your html file, either in the head or body sections.

Comment: Share your html code as well

Comment: Before you ask 'why is angular undefined', I would check the html source of the page to make sure that the angular file is being referenced properly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: \[ng:areq\] from angular controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21673404/error-ngareq-from-angular-controller)

Comment: i have added the html file

Answer (score 0):

I think the one and only reason is that you didn't include angular js file that that's why it is showing this error please make sure that it is add then check did you added the js file for ngMockE2E dependency

Comment: how should i add the js file for ngMockE2E?

Comment: NgMockE2E isn't a javascript library