# Angular service error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I have the below code implementation for service call but am getting the following error :
"angular.min.js:102 Error: [$injector:unpr]"

please advise me on the below error.thanks in advance

```
    var app1 = angular.module('homeapp', []);
app1.service('APIService', function ($http) {
    this.getSkill = function (userid) {
        //return $http.get("api/GetSkillRating", )
    return $http({
                url: "api/GetSkillRating",
                method: "GET",
                params: { userid: userid }
            });
    }
});  

app1.controller("HomeController", ['$scope', 'APIService', function ($scope, APIService) {
    $scope.skillrating =[];

    $scope.getAll = function () {
        var servCall = APIService.getSkill(userid);
        servCall.then(function (d) {
            $scope.skillrating = d.data;
        }, function (error) {
                $log.error('Oops! Something went wrong while fetching the data.')
            })
    }  

}])
```

Answer (score 1):

Add $scope as a dependency

```
app1.controller("HomeController", ['$scope','APIService', function ($scope, APIService) {
```

Comment: post your html as well

Comment: <body ng-app="homeapp" ng-controller="HomeController">
    <div id="tblSubs">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>SNo</th>
                <th>Soft Skill</th>
                <th>Self Rating</th>
            </tr>
            <tbody ng-repeat="sub in skillrating">
                <tr>
                    <td>{{sub.Id}}</td>
                    <td>{{sub.skill}}</td>
                    <td>{{sub.rating}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>

Answer (score 0):

you can't use $scope in service
and in controller you must inject $scope and $log

```
var app1 = angular.module('homeapp', []);

app1.service('APIService', function ($http) {
        this.getSkill = function () {
                //return $http.get("api/GetSkillRating", )
        return $http({
                                url: "api/GetSkillRating",
                                method: "GET",
                                params: { userid: $scope.userid }
                        });
        }
});

app1.controller("HomeController", ['$scope','$log','APIService', function ($scope, $log, APIService) {
        $scope.skillrating =[];
        getAll();

        function getAll() {
                var servCall = APIService.getSkill();
                servCall.then(function (d) {
                        $scope.skillrating = d.data;
                }, function (error) {
                                $log.error('Oops! Something went wrong while fetching the data.')
                        })
        }

}]);
```

Comment: @vimalkumar are you sure that you are defined only one time this line of code? var app1 = angular.module('homeapp', []);

Comment: I have it var app = angular.module('loginapp', []); for another view page logincontroller

Comment: can you add more code please? I want understand how this app is structured

Comment: you can see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21673404/error-ngareq-from-angular-controller how to manage more modules

Comment: I have both the modules in the same file for two different controllers.                 var app = angular.module('loginapp', []);                                                            var app1 = angular.module('homeapp', []);

Comment: ok, can you show me how you made the second module with its controller?

Comment: var app = angular.module('loginapp', []);
app.controller("LoginController", function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.login = function () {
        $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: '/Login/userlogin',
            data: $scope.user
        }).success(function (d) {
            if (d != 0) {
                userid = d;
                window.location.href = '/Home/Index';
            }
            else {
                alert(d);
            }
            $scope.user = null;

        }).error(function () {
            alert('failed');
        })
    }
})